# Thread(and irq) safe dynamic memory handler in C

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm looking for hints in using dynamic memory handler safe in multi-threaded system. Details of the issue:

1. written in C will run on cortex-M3 processor, with RTOS (CooCox OS),
2. [TLSF memory allocator](http://tlsf.baisoku.org/) will be used (other allocators might be used if I will find them better suited and they will be free and open-source),
3. Solution I'm looking for is using memory allocator safe from OS tasks and interrupts.

So far thought of 2 possible approaches, both have few yet unknown for me details:

1. disable and enable interrupts when calling allocator functions. Problem - if I'm not mistaking I can't play with interrupts disable and enable in normal mode, only in privileged mode (so if I'm not mistaken, that is only in interrupts), I need to do that from runtime also - to prevent interupts and task switching during memory handler operations.
2. call allocator from SWI. This one is still very unclear for me. 1st - is SWI same as FIQ (if so is it true that FIQ code needs to be written in asm - since allocator is written in C). Then still have few doubts about calling FIQ from IRQ (that scenarion would happen - tho not often), but most likely this part will not cause issues.

So any ideas on possible solutions for this situation?

Comment: The oly way I've been able to handle this is by not using the allocation directly in interrupts at all.  Instead, I use two sets of three queues, one set for IRQ, one for FIQ.  In each set, one queue supplies buffer indices/pointers to the tx interrupts, one supplies 'empty' buffers to the rx interrupts and the third is a return queue for filled rx buffers and 'used' tx buffers.  One thread manages each set of queues and runs when the interrupt signals a semaphore to say that the queues 'need attention'. The FIQ signals its semaphore by triggering an 'SWI' IRQ that runs when the FIQ exits.

Comment: @MartinJames: That does not sound like Cortex-M, but the older ARM7/9/10/11 or Cortex-R (not sure about -A). COretx-M has a completely different interrupt system with a full grown interrupt controller (NVIC) which includes true vectors, priorization (internal/external), etc. This mechanism would defy the whole architecture.

Comment: As far as I get from a short peek at the code, the interrupts will be blocked quite a while (allthough this might have a max. boundary). You should make sure your system can tolerate this _under_ _all_ _circumstances_. The SWI is not the thing for such (actually there is no SWI instruction, it has at least been renamed to SVC). The Cortex-M has a very clever exception system; you might have a look at SVPend instead of SVC. And (as I already stated) the Cortex-M has a different interupt system and not just two vectors.

Comment: You should first get very familar with the Cortex-M exception system. Most things you state in your question do not even exist or seem to make no sense to me (no offense). You might start with the Cortex-M3 TRM and Architecture Guide which cen be downloaded free from ARM (beware: there are two different Arch-Guides).

Also, your MCU-vendor should provide a reference manual (also called user('s) guide or similar; this is not the datasheet, but that might also be required).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your suggestions 1 and 2:

1. On Cortex-M3 you can enable and disable interrupts at any time in *privileged* level code through the [CMSIS intrinsics `__disable_irq`/`_enable_irq`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABEDCBC.html) functions.  *privileged* level is not restricted to *handler mode*; *thread mode* code can run at privileged level too (and in many small RTOS that is the default).
2. SWI and FIQ are concepts from legacy ARM architectures.  They do not exist in Cortex-M3.

You would not ideally want to perform memory allocation in an interrupt handler - even if the allocator is deterministic, it may still take significant amount of time; I can think of few reasons you would want to do that.

The best approach is to modify the tlsf code to use an RTOS mutex for each of the calls with external linkage.  [Other libraries](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlib/armlib_chr1358938915795.htm) I have used have stubs already in the library that normally do nothing, but which you can override with your own implementation to map it to any RTOS.

Now you cannot of course use a mutex in an ISR, but as I said you should probably not allocate memory there either.  If you really must perform allocation in an interrupt handler, then enable/disable interrupts is your only option, but you are then confounding all the real-time deterministic behaviour that an RTOS provides.  A better solution to that is to have your ISR do not more than issue an event-flag or semaphore to a thread context handler.  This allows you to use all RTOS services and scheduling, and the context switch time from ISR to a high priority thread will be insignificant compared to the memory allocation time.

Another possibility would be to not use this allocator at all, but instead use a fixed-block allocator using RTOS queues.  You pre-allocate blocks of memory (statically or dynamically), post pointers to the start of each block onto a queue, then to allocate you simply receive a pointer from the queue, and to free you post back to the queue. If memory is exhausted (queue is empty), you can baulk or block on the queue (do not block in an ISR though).  You can create multiple queues for different sized blocks, and use the one appropriate to your needs (ensuring you post back to the same queue of course!)

Comment: The instructions for __enable/disable_irq are protected for a good reason. They are not accessible from unprivileged mode. Memory allocation from an interrupt handler is common practice and simplifies system design. This expecially if using priority levels. However, you are right the allocator must not take more than a given time. The actual time depends on acceptable interrupt timing and latency. Standard allocators are most times not the right thing for this anyway.

Comment: Regarding `__enable_irq` - my error, in simple RTOS environments it is common for all software to run in privileged mode - so I have never encountered the restriction on my Cortex-M3 projects, but in any case while *handler mode* is *always* privileged, *thread mode* may run at either  *privileged* or *unprivileged* level.  Regarding memory allocation in ISRs, common practice where!?  Not if it is intrinsically not thread-safe, or the thread-safety mechanism is blocking.  What real-time embedded systems environment are you seeing that *common practice*?

Comment: Depends. I do agree it is not common to use the standard malloc&co - for the reasons you gave. However, in small embedded systems like Cortex-M based ones, they are not a good choice must times anyway. A special block allocator is actually used quite often to get/release buffers, etc.

Comment: Regarding protection: that depends. I currently work on such a system. Not quite easy to have the system locked with only 8 regions, but it works with the right approach. Oh, and my allocator _is_ thread (and interrupt) safe. And non-blocking. But (for few clocks) locking.

Comment: @Olaf : Indeed; I briefly describe such a block allocator in my answer.  I would not describe that as "dynamic memory allocation" in the sense that it is does not involve management of a heap, but rather a pool.

Comment: Using preallocated memory pools to act as pseudo dynamic alocator isn't an option in my case (from my experience this way usually adds big overhead when you need possibility to get memory which is big compared to whole pool size). And for SWI if I'm not mistaken it is called SVC, well at least SVC is called over SWI instruction.

Comment: And about use in IRQ's. That I want due to possibility to simplify code and it would be used only in few interrupts (so far I think only about peripheral TX DMA irq - so after tx is completed IRQ could delete memory pool it was sending from). Also I found out that there is 2nd way to disable IRQ's - over BASEPRI, which would disable only interrupts with lower priority than requested. So with it I think it would be possible to disable only interrupts which can use alocator and systick (to prevent OS from switching content).

Comment: @LaurynasKlimavicius The OS should not switch context on a systick until the interrupt context is exited, so that is not a problem.

Comment: Yes. But it can switch content while not in IRQ. So disabling systick and IRQ's which can use alocator I would make alocator safe to use, if I thought it through right.

Comment: @LaurynasKlimavicius :  I see what you mean - its still a bad idea.  If you system is not truely hard-realtime you will get away with it, but if you need response time determinism in the order of microseconds your solution will break.  It is just not a general solution.

Comment: @Clifford: Call it a pool, but it is still a dynamic memory allocation/free mechanism. As I wrote, most embedded systems actually do not need a full grown heap-management with split/join of blocks, etc. This because there is a very high propability for the heap to fragment such that an allocation will eventually fail over time allthough there is enough memory left. Problem is that this may happan in a critical moment where a system restart might result in damage of external components. Oh, and I am not talking about pool(s) with a single block size, but more generalized.

Comment: @Olaf :  We may be in *violent agreement* and just quibbling about imprecise terminology.  The "traditional" heap is part of the runtime environment, (and in C++ at least is intrinsically built into the language via default new/delete operators). If I were to statically allocate a block of memory and push pointers to a queue, I have implemented a memory management mechanism independent of the heap.  So all I am saying is that one should ensure you have complete control or knowledge of the behaviour and performance of your allocation mechanism.

Comment: @Clifford: I am actually talking about a daynamic block allocation mechanism. Much like a heap, but without the fragment/merge algorithm. Yes, it might have something of a pool, as it manages blocks in fixed sizes. However, it is used as a full replacement for the classical allocator (with some restrictions on max. size). About the other aspect I _do_ agree. But the TO actually wanted to use his own algorithm. I just had a short peek, but there seem to be no indetermined loops, so it might be possible to keep realtime contraints. Just to free blocks, a deferred int-handler might be sufficient.

Comment: @Clifford: Problem is that in a bare-metal embedded system, there is actually no _standard_ heap algorithm. That's why FreeRTOS for instance provides four different implementations (of which none suited my needs, so I had to use two own in parallel). This is actually a freestanding environment, for which the C standard does not even require stdlib to exist (along with most other headers). (Not sure about C++). So one cannot assume to have a heap/pool/kettle/bag/... at all.